# different colors for connected edges in UV editor

Tags: uv-image-editor, color

Is it possible to to see what edges/verts are connected on the 3d model inside the uv editor by render them in different colors? This would be so great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the UV/Image Editor Header, select Shared Vertex in the Sticky Selection Mode.
[image]

Set the Edge selection mode.

[image]

Select an edge to highlight the shared edge (and vertices)

[image]

Comment: No i am taking about some kind of function that is active all the time. Any way thanks for trying.